# this.setOptions is not a function in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, upgrade, joomla1.5

I faced some issues when I was doing upgrade my Joomla version 1.5 to the latest current version. When I have to go for an upgrade version using jUpgrade component, it gives me a jquery error. Like this :

**Type Error : this.setOptions is not a function in modal.js**

I have disabled this but it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very nice solution, but you can change **this.setOptions(this.presets)** to **this.options = this.presets** in media/system/js/modal.js.

After upgrade don't forget to set file to previous state.